# Xubuntu 18.04 LiveDVD AOK at native screen res 1024x768; when boots from HDD, resolution drops to 640x480

Tags: system-installation, sis-graphics

I am new to Linux, and installed Xubuntu onto an old (Vista-vintage) laptop with SIS 771/671 graphics. The LiveDVD seemed OK at the native screen resolution of 1024x788; after install completed and it boots from the HDD, the resolution defaults to 640 x 480.

I looked up this problem; it seems to be common, but with no certain solution (as far as I can understand).

1) How do I troubleshoot this and move towards a solution?
2) Am I looking at an impossible situation?
3) Why does it work from the DVD at native screen resolution (1024x788)?

Thank you.

Comment: _Bob Hide_, when you face a problem like this, you try solution #1; if that doesn't fix it, try #2; try #3; lather, rinse, repeat.  Please keep track of what you found when you searched, and the results when you tried them, then add them to the original question with [edit]; please don't use Add Comment, we want all _your_ findings up there in the question where all can see them, so please use [edit].